# jsapi distinguish speaker from another one

Tags: java, speech, jsapi

I'm developing an application where authentication is made with the voice of a user. So it has to be possible to distinguish the users. I know MARF should me a possible SDK, but it's kind of old, so I was wondering of JSAPI can be used for this. It's not necessary to translate speech to text but to distinguish a user for another one.

Comment: So all I have to do to hack a log-in is to use my mobile phone to record part of a conversation with the person I want to impersonate, then replay that for the app.?  Cool.  :)

Answer (score 0):

No you can not recognize speakers with jsapi.

Comment: is there a library that can?

Comment: MARF, you named it already. Actually every library that implements GMM can do speaker recognition.